# What words satisfy this requirement: The singular form ends in "s" and the plural form drops the "s"

Tags: grammatical-number

Recently, I realized that I did not know of any words in the English language whose singular form ends in an "s" and whose plural form drops that "s."

I was wondering if anyone either knew the answer or knew of a means of learning the answer (e.g, a database to search words by oddly-specific criteria)

Comment: Look for words ending in -us that have plurals in -i. Such as "fungus, fungi."

Comment: Why would you imagine that there were such words? Is this a riddle somewhere?

Comment: Someone asked me to think of a word which ended in "es" in the singular and dropped the "s" in the plural, but I couldn't think of any. Additionally, I couldn't think of any words off the top of my head which simply ended with "s" in the singular and dropped the "s" in the plural

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are "foreign plurals",i.e. words which come from foreign languages,such as "cactus-cacti,corpus-corpora" etc.